# PowerShell Command has output when used in a prompt, but not when used in a script (Update-TfsWorkspace)

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015, powershell-cmdlet, tfs-power-tools

I am working with the PSSnapin Teamfoundation.PowerShell, specifically with the cmdlet, Update-TfsWorkspace.

I am attempting to script and automate a process involving getting the latest content from TFS. When I use the command:

```
Update-TfsWorkspace -force -item $somepath -recurse -overwrite
```

in a PowerShell prompt, I get this output:

```
Replacing   468256 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile1.txt
Replacing   468256 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile2.txt
Replacing   510850 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile3.txt
Replacing   468256 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile4.txt
Replacing   468256 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile5.txt
Replacing   510850 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile6.txt
Replacing   468256 C:\Path\MorePath\SomeFile7.txt
```

Thats what I want and expect to see. However, when I execute the same command in a script rather than directly in the prompt I just get spaces instead of output. The command executes successfully and it is clear that it worked, but I don't get the output. See the following link:
[Image of Empty Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8av6.png)

It does the same thing when using Start-Transcript to log the process to a file. I get output, but the output is just spaces. [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar7nV.png)

I need the output from this command for the log and the stubborn refusal of the script to generate it seems to be beyond my expertise. Any one have any idea why this occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Note sure, because I don't use it, it looks like this CmdLet don't write on OutPut, but only on host (see : [Understanding Streams, Redirection, and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/))

A trick is to put your code in `MyTFSScript.PS1` ansd call :

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -file MyTFSScript.PS1 > MyTFSScript.log
```